# Getting started with discord.py in pythonista

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pythonista

I’ve just started trying to create a discord bot in Pythonista using an online tutorial, I installed StaSh and discord.py and I have the following code but I keep getting an error:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run("my_token")
```

the error is “no module named ‘ctypes.macholib’” and i don’t understand it at all. could someone please help? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/omz/Pythonista-Issues/issues/311#issuecomment-398715503 ?

Comment: @Mihai thank you so much! this solved the problem perfectly!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then, maybe it will help someone else.